# FlatList is hidden after big content

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

With React Native 0.64, I would like to display an image followed by comments, just like instagram.

Here is what I did in simplified *(the styles of the image and the comments are well managed, I do not put the code not to pollute the question)* :

```
import {
  Image,
  FlatList,
  View
} from 'react-native'

const Post = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <View>
      <Image ... />
      <FlatList
        data={comments.filter(item => null === item.reply)}
        renderItem={({ item: comment, index }) => (
          <CommentRow
            comment={comment}
            index={index}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(comment) => comment.id}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Ok, here is the result :

[image]

But I can't reach the comments, because the picture takes all the height. I can't scroll (logical, there is no scrollview). **I don't want to resize my image.**

If I add all the content in a scrollview, like this :

```
const Post = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <ScrollView >
      <Image ... />
      <FlatList
        data={comments.filter(item => null === item.reply)}
        renderItem={({ item: comment, index }) => (
          <CommentRow
            comment={comment}
            index={index}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(comment) => comment.id}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

**I have this error :**

> VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.

If I add scrollview before FlatList the navigation is very bad and the display too, like this :

[image]

Comment: Instead of nesting the `FlatList` and `Image` inside of a `View` component, try setting the image inside of the header of your `FlatList` by using its [`ListHeaderComponent`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent) property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you dont use pagination you can use `map` instead of `FlatList` and follow the code bellow:

**No pagination**

```
const Post = () => {
...
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Image .../>
      {comments
        .filter((item) => null === item.reply)
        .map((comment, index) => (
          <CommentRow {...{ comment, index }} key={index.toString()} />
        ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

but if you has pagination put image on the `ListHeaderComponent` of the FlatList and follow the code bellow:

**pagination**

```
import {
  Image,
  FlatList,
  View
} from 'react-native'

const Post = () => {
  ...

  return (      
      <FlatList
        ListHeaderComponent={()=>(<Image ... />)}
        data={comments.filter(item => null === item.reply)}
        renderItem={({ item: comment, index }) => (
          <CommentRow
            comment={comment}
            index={index}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(comment) => comment.id}
         /** pagination */
      />
  )
}
```